# Facebook API Authenticate on a different machine

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, mobile

Assuming it is possible to transfer the Facebook API access token from some web app to my mobile app (via physical storage or network), will my mobile app be able to use that token as a regularly acquired token (as if the mobile app itself requested the token from Facebook)?

Is this procedure allowed in the Facebook API's terms of service?

Will the mobile app be able to cache that transferred token and use it as its own?

Basically, what I want is for the user to do Facebook Login and authenticate on one machine, and use the acquired token on a different one (e.g mobile app).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your mobile app to go through facebook's oauth steps onload and if the user has already authenticated the app, he will get logged in right away, since you'll get an access token at this point of time, save that in the mobile app.

Automatic login triggers are now being used on both stackoverflow and quora. (if you sign up here through facebook, when you visit the site, you'll get signed in again - same for quora).

Also, access tokens grant access to a particular 'facebook app'. If your mobile app uses the same app id, then you can certainly reuse the same access token on the mobile device.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. So in short I just need to have the same app id across the machine and mobile device for the token to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yep, we can reuse it. I got an access token from mobile app then it's applicable on web browser.